# WooCommerce Shortcode To Display Cart Items by Category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

Are there any existing shortcodes (or plugins) to display cart items by category?

Right now, there is the `[woocommerce_cart]` short code that we can use.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Did you get any solution on it ? I need solution similar. thanks

Comment: @ShamimAhmed Still didn't find any luck.